# How to show/hide div based on select option using typescript

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i want to show hide div based on dropdown selection using typescript.

html.file:

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select">
  <option selected>single</option>
  <option value="1">Weekly</option>
  <option value="2">Monthly</option>
  <option value="3">Yearly</option>
</select>

<div class="single">single working fine</div>
<div class="weekly">Weekly working fine</div>
<div class="monthly">monthly working fine</div>
<div class="yearly">yearly working fine</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use two way binding `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` and `*ngIf` to show/hide div

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue">
  <option value="0" selected>single</option>
  <option value="1">Weekly</option>
  <option value="2">Monthly</option>
  <option value="3">Yearly</option>
</select>

<div class="single" *ngIf="selectedValue == 0">single working fine</div>
<div class="weekly" *ngIf="selectedValue == 1">Weekly working fine</div>
<div class="monthly" *ngIf="selectedValue == 2">monthly working fine</div>
<div class="yearly" *ngIf="selectedValue == 3">yearly working fine</div>
```

Demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6bxz9y

Comment: its working fine. tanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **ngModel** in select box. So that you can store the latest value in it and in div you need to use **ngIf** condition

```
<select class="browser-default custom-select" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
  <option selected>single</option>
  <option value="1">Weekly</option>
  <option value="2">Monthly</option>
  <option value="3">Yearly</option>
</select>
```

In Ts file, just define **selectedOption** variable.

```
  <div class="single" *ngIf="selectedOption === 1">single working fine</div>
    <div class="weekly"  *ngIf="selectedOption === 2">weekly working fine</div>
    <div class="monthly"  *ngIf="selectedOption === 3">monthly working fine</div>
    <div class="yearly">yearly working fine</div>
```

In DIV you need to use **ngIf** like this.

Comment: its working fine. tanks